# heroku bash not recognizing sequelize command

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and I have followed the steps as provided in http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/heroku/ but whenever i try to run the sequelize command in heroku bash it replies me with command not found.

Answer (score 16):

This part seems to have been split of into a different `npm` package. To adjust for that install

```
npm install --save sequelize-cli
```

and make sure it is also on heroku

```
git commit -m'Added sequelize CLI' package.json
git push heroku master
```

That should do. While we are at it, the migrate command seems to have changes slightly, too, to

```
sequelize db:migrate
```